# AndroidStudio Private Resources

Tags: java, android

Trying to use an Holo appearance in a TextView I get the `"Resource is not public"` error.

I read that a way to solve the problem is to copy the files into my application.
But I have not understood how to do it.

May you help me ? Thanks

Comment: Please can you provide some code.

Comment: Try using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` under TextView.